# onclick any input or textarea except one do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are many input fields and textarea fields in my page.The task is if someone click's on anyone of those except one with id "xyz" event should fire but only first time(click).After first click if the user clicks in anyone of those input,textboxes event should not fire.

```
$("input[type=button], textarea").not("#xyz"){

//Event shout fire but only on first click
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use easy condition for this.

```
let shouldFire = true;
$("input[type=button], textarea").not("#xyz"){
 if(!shouldFire) return;
 shouldFire = false;

// Code to be executed just once
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(selector).one(event,callback)`:

```
$("input[type=button], textarea").not("#xyz").one("click", function(){
  //Event shout fire but only on first click
});
```

Comment: .one() will look for clicks ineach input and textarea once.Means if you click on same textbox again event will not fire but on click another textbox event will fire.